# Checking input date format

Tags: excel, vba, date

Anybody knows how to check the input date format in the textbox in vba ?
I have this code but I'm uncertain of the output. The input format of the user should be in `mm/dd/yyyy`. if not, then it will pop out a message saying: Use the mm/dd/yyy date format.

```
If Not Format(txtStartDate.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy") Then
    MsgBox "Please use the  mm/dd/yyyy date format."
    txtStartDate.setFocus
    Exit sub
End If
```

I'm just very unsure of what I'm into. thanks!

Comment: How do you plan to determine whether 07/04/2016 is 04-Jul-2016 or 07-Apr-2015?

Comment: That's also my next step. As of now, I still don't know what to do.

Comment: Check `If Len(txtStartDate.Value) = 10 And UBound(Split(txtStartDate.Value, Chr(47))) = 2 Then` it is most likely text that looks like a date in mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy format.

Answer (score 3):

```
      Dim regEx As New RegExp
      regEx.Pattern = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}"
      Dim inputstring As String
      inputstring = "10/2/200"

      If Not regEx.test(inputstring) Then
      MsgBox "Please use the  mm/dd/yyyy date format."
        Exit Sub
      End If
```

Comment: the exactly the same result as output in your code can be achieved just using `Like`, e.g. `If Not inputstring Like "##/##/####" Then`, but I think that it is not really what OP needs. Your code will verify only that `inputsring` contains `2 numbers / 2 numbers / 4 numbers`, but not that first two numbers are months (01-12) and so on, e.g. if `inputstring` will be equal to `"99/99/9999"` your code will not notify about wrong data input. I think that you should rework `pattern` to get more accurate verification... +1 from my side.

Comment: this pattern will give more accurate result `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$` with a year between 1900 and 2099, and also `inputsring` should be additionally verified against `isdate("02/31/2010")` which is should return `false` because such date doesn't exists